# How to fill an empty character array?

Tags: arrays, matlab

I'm trying decode an array of 1's and 0's using variable length coding. For example, if the string is `[1 0 1 1]`, and `A = [1 0]` and `B = [1 1]`, my program should give me a string something like: `['A', 'B']`.

I first created an empty character array `x = repmat(char(0),1,10)`

But now when I detect a code word using a for loop and if statements, how do I add the character to this array `x`? Would it display the characters in the decoded string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, pre-defining the length of `x` is unnecessary in MATLAB because the language allows you resize arrays on-the-fly.  That being said, preallocation is a sometimes a good idea because it will run faster.

Assuming you want to preallocate the length of `x`, you can assign a character to an element in x directly:

```
% Preallocate x
x = repmat(char(0),1,10);

% Assign a character to x
x(1) = 'A';
```

Where you can replace the `1` with any element in the array.

The challenge with this is that you need to keep track of where you are at in this preallocated array.  If you already wrote characters to positions 1, 2, and 3, you need to know that the next assignment will write to the 4th element of x: `x(4) = ...`.

A more elegant solution might be the following:

```
x = [];
if foundLetter
    x(end) = 'A';
end
```

This adds the letter `A` to the end of the pre-defined character array `x`.  It doesn't require that you preallocate the length of `x`.

Comment: The second code snippet returns an error if the length of x is zero.
>> x(end) = 2
Attempted to access x(0); index must be a positive integer or logical.
Even if it were preallocated and has length other than zero the last element of x would just keep getting overwritten, correct? It is necessary to update a counter variable or use the iterated variable in the for loop depending on how the decoding is performed.

Comment: I'm getting an error. My program checks each bit in the code one by one. Assume that A = [1 1 ], B = [1 0 1] and C = [1 0 0].For example, if my code word is code=[1 0 1 1 1], it will first check code(n), where n = 1. If code(n) == 1, it will check if code(n+1) == 0. Then if that's true, it checks code(n+3). If code(n+3) == 1, then it knows it stores the letter as 'B', otherwise it will store as C. The problem arises when the code word is short. As if it's [1 0 1]. When it checks code(n+3), it finds nothing, because the code word has ended, so it returns an error. How do I fix this?

Comment: @Kaya311 See if the code I've added helps. You should be able to easily expand the dictionary or make small changes if necessary. Of course this doesn't incorporate checking for a corrupted message - assumes a perfectly valid message with no unknown code sequences.

Comment: I believe the "more elegant" solution is incorrect. You create an empty matrix `x`, and then try to assign `'A'` to the last element. That doesn't make sense since it's empty. If you try to run it, you will get an error.

Answer (score 0):

You can index the character array `x` just as you would an array of doubles.

```
x(1) = 'A'; %Assign the char 'A' to the first element of x
.
.
.
x(10) = 'B'; %Assign the char 'B' to the tenth element of x
```

Here is a short example of what you would like to do.

```
clear decodedMsg
% define a dictionary between codes and corresponding characters
code{1,1} = 'A'; code{1,2} = '11';
code{2,1} = 'B'; code{2,2} = '101';
code{3,1} = 'C'; code{3,2} = '100';

% declare a sample message, corresponds to ABCBA
msg = [1 1 1 0 1 1 0 0 1 0 1 1 1];

%keeps track of the number of matches found, used to add to decodedMsg
counter = 1;
% get length of message and use to iterate through the msg
N = length(msg);
buffer = []; %must declare buffer if you are to use (end + 1) indexing later on
for i = 1:N
    buffer(end + 1) = msg(i);                   %add the next msg value to the buffer
    strBuf = strrep(num2str(buffer),' ','');    %convert buffer into string, e.x. [1 0 1] => '101'
    findMatch = ismember(code(:,2),strBuf);     %findMatch contains a 1 if a match is found
    if any(findMatch)                           %if any element in findMatch is 1
        decodedMsg(counter) = code{findMatch,1};%use that element to index a char in code cell array
        counter = counter + 1;                  %increment counter since another code was found
        buffer = [];                            %reset buffer for next string of 1s and 0s
    end
end
```